# Page numbers not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone have any idea why my page numbers are not listing inside of the pagination div? I'm using the tablesorter.pager plugin.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../inc/dbconfig.php");
require("../inc/global_functions.php");

// find out how many rows are in the table 
$query = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',firstName,lastName) AS name, username, emailAddress, userID FROM manager_users WHERE statusID != 4";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

$fileName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pageName = "User Accounts";
$userData = $_SESSION['user_data'];
$userID = $userData['userID'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('a.bt_green').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.right_content').load('forms/addnew/' + $(this).attr('id'));
});

$('#usersPageList').tablesorter().tablesorterPager({container:$('#pagination'),cssPageLinks:'a.pageLink', positionFixed: false});

$('table tr').click(function() {

    checkBox = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');

    if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');

});

$('.ask').jConfirmAction();

$('.ask2').jConfirmAction();    

});
</script>

<h2>User Accounts</h2> 

<table id="usersPageList" class="rounded-corner">

<thead>

    <tr>

        <th scope="col" class="rounded-first"></th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Email Address</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Username</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Edit</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded-last">Delete</th>

    </tr>

</thead>

<tfoot>

    <tr>

        <td colspan="5" class="rounded-foot-left"><em>Displays all of the registered and verified users!</em></td>
        <td class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

</tfoot>

<tbody>

    <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"users[]\" value=\"".$row['userID']."\"/></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['emailAddress']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/user_edit.png\" alt=\"\" title=\"\" border=\"0\" /></a></td>";
            echo "<td>";
            if (($row['userID'] !== '10000') && ($row['userID'] !== $userID)){
                echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"ask\"><img src=\"images/trash.png\" class=\"delete\" alt=\"\" title=\"\" border=\"0\" id=\"".$row['userID']."\" /></a>";
            }
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?> 

</tbody>

</table>

<div id="pagination"></div>

<?php
addRemove($fileName,$pageName);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="myhiddenPageToken" id="myhiddenPageToken" value="useraccounts" />
```

EDIT POST:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a.bt_green').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.right_content').load('forms/addnew/' + $(this).attr('id'));
});

 $('#usersPageList').tablesorter().tablesorterPager({container:$('#pagination'),cssPageLinks:'a.pageLink', positionFixed: false});

$('table tr').click(function() {

    checkBox = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');

    if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');

});

$('.ask').jConfirmAction();

$('.ask2').jConfirmAction();    

});
</script>

<h2>User Accounts</h2> 

<table id="usersPageList" class="rounded-corner">

<thead>

    <tr>

        <th scope="col" class="rounded-first"></th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Email Address</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Username</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded">Edit</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded-last">Delete</th>

    </tr>

</thead>

<tfoot>

    <tr>

        <td colspan="5" class="rounded-foot-left"><em>Displays all of the registered and verified users!</em></td>
        <td class="rounded-foot-right">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

</tfoot>

    <tbody>

        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="10000"/></td><td>KOW Management</td><td>kowmanagement@kansasoutlawwrestling.com</td><td>Administrator</td><td><a href="#"><img src="images/user_edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="10001"/></td><td>Jeff Davidson</td><td>xtremer360@yahoo.com</td><td>xtremer360</td><td><a href="#"><img src="images/user_edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td><td></td></tr> 

</tbody>

</table>

<div id="pagination"></div>

<a href="" class="bt_green" id="useraccounts.php"><span class="bt_green_lft"></span><strong>Add New User Accounts</strong><span class="bt_green_r"></span></a><a href="" class="bt_blue"><span class="bt_blue_lft"></span><strong>View all User Accounts</strong><span class="bt_blue_r"></span></a><a href="" class="bt_red ask2"><span class="bt_red_lft"></span><strong>Delete User Accounts</strong><span class="bt_red_r"></span></a><input type="hidden" name="myhiddenPageToken" id="myhiddenPageToken" value="useraccounts" />
```

Comment: Are you able to post your final HTML output on jsfiddle.net or perhaps give us a link to a page where this page gets rendered?  (Since it's probably a JavaScript and/or HTML structure issue). Thanks!

Comment: I've been at this ALL day. If someone can PLEASE IM on AIM or YAHOO. (xtremer360)

Comment: Actually, are you able to post the full HTML output of your entire page? (Visit your page, View Source, paste in here).  There are going to be several resources that we'll need to see as well.  Usually, any JS error (even in another part of your page) can often halt the rest of your scripts.  One thing I noticed is that your <tfoot> section is above your <tbody> section.  Does anything happen if you move your <tfoot> below <tbody>, OR, as a test, remove your <tfoot> all together?

Comment: I recreated your issue and now I have it working, but I have no idea. Just wanted to let you know I'm on the case and not to give up hope ;)

Comment: Well thank you Tak. Very much appreciated. This is odd that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tablesorterPager plugin to work in your code I had to add a pagination form myself. I changed the pagination div to this, copied from the [documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html):

```
<div id="pagination">
    <form>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="../addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The tablesorterPager now works, and also fixes the tablesorter which breaks if tablesorterPager can't find the form.

I can't see any reference in jquery.tablesorter.pager.js to generate the form itself, so I guess you'll have to create it server-side based on the number of results in the table, and the number of results you'd like per page.

Hope that helps

Comment: The only problem is that I need the links to appear like so. <div class="pagination">
        <span class="disabled"><< prev</span><span class="current">1</span><a href="">2</a><a href="">3</a><a href="">4</a><a href="">5</a>…<a href="">10</a><a href="">11</a><a href="">12</a>...<a href="">100</a><a href="">101</a><a href="">next >></a>

        </div>

Comment: Ah I see, quite a different question ;)

Comment: i say that because it is part of the template that exists here: kansasoutlawwrestling.com/manager/index2.html

Comment: I would mark this question as answered and start another question about PHP pagination links with 1000s of results. No doubt someone has done this before who can help. Do you have 1000s of users on the system though?

Comment: ok I might try and get some additional help on a different forum thank you.